# Allow cookies from certain websites?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, safari-extensions, cookies

I have some problems with cookies, I don't want cookies everywhere, but only for certain websites.

What I have done right now is I allow cookies, then do the thing where a cookie is saved, then block cookies. But some websites requires me to always have cookies on for some reason, in this case Stackexchange and another website.

So does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I know how to do that in Firefox but not in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox you can do that.

I have not found a way in Safari, so one needs a external app (3d party).

Here is one you might like:

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31018/safari-cookies

[image: cookies]